# Unable to process strings in files with different encoding [Not accepting answers]

Tags: string, go, utf-8

I am trying to process the strings present in a particular file, The file is written in **English**. The problem arises when the encoding of the file differs from "UTF-8". But the file with encoding as "UTF-16-le" does not behave as expected. My main goal is manipulate the strings from the read file. For example the `strings.TrimSpace()` only works with the **UTF-8** file,

***I am aware that golang only supports UTF-8 by default***, Any alternate approach would be helpful.

**Personal Question**

> Also I would like to point out, many new programming languages, do process the strings irrespective of the encoding, And why does Go only support UTF-8. If at least there would be an alternative way to pass the encoding format to the reader, that might still help.

#### What I tried

1. I tried using utf-8 and utf-16 std packages

#### Code

##### (main.go)

sample code to show the difference.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func processFile(src string) {
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(src)

    fmt.Println("--- original source ---")
    fmt.Println(string(data))
    fmt.Println(http.DetectContentType(data))

    fmt.Println("\n--- modified source ---")
    for _, val := range strings.Split(string(data), "\n") {
        fmt.Println(strings.TrimSpace(val))
    }
}

func main() {
    processFile("./utf-16-english.txt")
    processFile("./utf-8-english.txt")
}
```

#### File-1

##### (utf-8-english.txt)

```
Hello
    This is
        Sample
            Document
```

#### File-2

##### (utf-16-english.txt)

```
Hello
    This is
        Sample
            Document
```

##### EDIT

1. Seems that the only way to process strings in a better way is to convert them to UTF-8. Kindly refer the marked answer.
2. As per comments I have written the result from the program to respective files. And the special symbols are not present, but the process with strings, works fine with UTF-8

Comment: I'm not convinced that the original file is indeed encoded using UTF-16LE. If you read up on that encoding ([this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) is OK), you'll find out that the characters from the repertoire of (printable) ASCII (such as those of the word "Hello") are encoded using two bytes each, with the leading 0x00—so that, say, 'H' is encoded as two bytes, 0x00, 0x84, in that order. The output rendered in the upper-left part of your screenshot does not look like it have _any_ 0x00 bytes, though.

Comment: …hence, yes, this might merely be an artefact of your terminal emulator ("console window", "terminal window", etc) and should you have shown us a proper [hex dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump) of both the original pieces of data (and you [_should have_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/720999)), I could say that for sure, but just from looking at the screenshots, I'm not convinced it's UTF-16.

Comment: For future refence (and in order to not ask questions like this one—which are trivially resolved using 15 minutes of searching the Internet), Go has a set of 3rd-party packages, [`golang.org/x/text`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text) which can deal with most of legacy (non-Unicode) text encodings—such as ISO character sets, Windows and MS-DOS "code pages" etc, and also there's a package which can interpret "charsets" from the values of the `Content-Encoding` HTTP header field.

Comment: Thankyou, Will surely look it up. Also this is my first question, Will surely note the points mentioned.

Comment: Oh, in UTF-16LE, the letter 'H' is encoded as the sequence 0x84, 0x00—that is, not with the leading 0x00, but rather with the trailing. (I'm always tripped by this, being accustomed to the left-to-right writing notation where the least significant bits of a number are the rightmost.) Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: And while we're at it, one more note: it's also possible to work with text by decoding encodings like UTF-16 directly into slices of `rune`—`[]rune`, which, in Go, are designed specifically to store Unicode code points as 32-bit integers. This way, you won't get many of the goodness stock `string` brings in—such as the `fmt` package and the `+` operator, but this approach might nevertheless be convenient/useful for low-level operations/analysis etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decode the utf-16 encoded file. The decoding will convert the input to utf-8, after which you can use the string libraries to process the input.

You can use something like this:

```
import "unicode/utf16"

func processFile(src string, decode func(in[]byte) string) {
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(src)

    fmt.Println("--- original source ---")
    fmt.Println(decode(data))

    fmt.Println("\n--- modified source ---")
    for _, val := range strings.Split(decode(data), "\n") {
        fmt.Println(strings.TrimSpace(val))
    }
}

func main() {
    processFile("./utf-16-english.txt",func(in []byte) string {
        return string(utf16.Decode(in)) })
    processFile("./utf-8-english.txt",func(in []byte) string {
         return string(in)})
}
```